# JavaScript: Can I use square brackets ([]) operator as a function?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible for any arbitrary object to obtain a reference to an accessor function that would act exactly as `[]` operator?

Something like the following?:

```
function get(x) { return this[x] }
```

So that if I had an object *foo* instead of doing `foo['bar']` I could call `foo.get('bar')`

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here?  The question itself, as asked, seems pretty weird.  What's wrong with `[ ]`?

Comment: Yes it is possible, when written correctly.

Comment: Here is a working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/RS6ET/

Comment: John Resig wrote a nice article about getters and setters: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/ In his article he explains how to create custom getters and setters.

Comment: The thing is that if you have a reference to an object, and you have a property name, then the `[ ]` operator already allows you to access the property value. Yes, you can write a function to use the operator, but how does that make anything *less* complicated?

Comment: @Pointy, having [] as a function would be useful for writing programs in functional paradigm (using it as a higher order function to compose other functions, doing partial function applications and so on).

Comment: Isn't `get` a reserved word in ecmascript 5? I would probably avoid it.

Comment: I used 'get' as an example. Read it as "_some_imaginary_function_"

Comment: @Tim - nope, "get" is not reserved, but it's generally used for a specific purpose, as in getters and setters, so using another name would be a good idea anyway.

Comment: @adeneo , yeah I just looked it up, you are right. Yeah, got it, wajda , I was just thinking out loud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a function:

```
function get( propertyName ) {
  return this[ propertyName ];
}
```

Then you can bind that function to some particular object:

```
var myObject = { /* ... */ }; // that looks like a little face, kind-of
var getter = get.bind(myObject);
```

Now, why is that interesting? The only reason I can think of is that it gives you an object (the bound version of the function) that you can pass to other code, allowing that code to *get* property values but not *update* them. I suppose that's kind-of useful, though I can't say I've found myself wanting it.

You can add a "get" function to the Object prototype, but if you do so I'd do it in such a way as to make it non-enumerable. Otherwise, you may have weird behavior of `for ... in` loops:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "get", {
  value: function( key ) { return this[key]; }
});
```

Another interesting thing to contemplate if you're doing functional-style programming is the semantics of your "get" function. The sample I did above makes it possible to create a function to get a *particular* property of an object too, in addition to being a getter for any property:

```
var getSomeObjectName = get.bind( someObject, "name" );
```

Now all that the function "getSomeObjectName" will do is fetch the "name" property value.

It might also be interesting to consider higher-order functions. A really useful notion is that of a "pluck" function, to pull a particular attribute from an object. It's kind-of like "get" but I'd write it differently:

```
function pluck(propertyName, object) {
  object = object || this;
  return object[propertyName];
}
```

Now I can make a getter as before, pretty much the same way:

```
var getter = pluck.bind( someObject );
```

Alternatively, I can make a "plucker" for a particular property name that will get that property from any object:

```
var getName = pluck.bind(null, "name");
```

Now I can call:

```
getName( someOtherObject )
```

and that's effectively like calling

```
pluck( "name", someOtherObject )
```

because I've "pre-loaded" the first parameter ("name") in the "getName" function. That becomes really useful with things like the `.map()` facility:

```
var myArray = [
  { name: "Thomas", type: "tank engine" }
, { name: "Flipper", type: "dolphin" }
, { name: "Rocinante", type: "horse" }
// ...
];

var allNames = myArray.map(pluck.bind(null, "name"));
```

You can of course write a wrapper function to hide the somewhat ugly call to `.bind`:

```
function plucker( name ) {
  return pluck.bind(null, name);
}

allNames = myArray.map( plucker("name") );
```

Comment: I didn't know about `bind`. Is it a ECMA 5 standard? Although this solution is not exactly what I was looking for, but since there is no such native function this solution seems to be the best one. I like it better than altering Object prototype as it doesn't pollute the global namespace and I have a control on this accessor function visibility.

Comment: @wajda yes, `.bind()` is a fairly new standard method on the Function prototype. It's available in all new browsers, and there are versions for older browsers available. Altering built-in object prototypes is itself a controversial practice. If you do it, you should make sure that the added function is made non-enumerable. (I'll update my answer.)

Comment: Re the reasons, yes, I need to pass []-ish function to another function to read my object properties in a uniform way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, by prototyping

```
var foo = {bar : 3};

Object.prototype.getz = function(what) {
    return this[what];
}

var value = foo.getz('bar'); // outputs 3
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/s7Qen/)

No idea why you would need it ?

Comment: I know how to do it via prototype. I was wondering if there is already such function, so I don't need altering the Object prototype. The biggest problem with this approach is possible interference with other libraries, since changes in Object prototype is visible everywhere.

Comment: What a strange comment, if you knew how to do it, why did you ask, and what are the chances another library is using Object.getz, or that it would ever be an issue, I'd say close to nill. And no, there's no such function available natively, that's what dot and bracket notation is for.

Comment: @adeneo I don't think it is a strange comment. Altering Object.prototype is widely considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can.

http://jsfiddle.net/sdaDK/

```
var foo = {
    bar: 'foo2',
    get: function (a) { return this[a]; }
}

alert(foo.get('bar'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need this function only for one object then you can do

```
var myObject = {
    x: 'anything',
    get: function (x) { return this[x]; }
}
alert(myObject.get('x'));
```

Or if you need this for all object you need to extend the prototype of Object class

```
var myObject = {
    x: 'anything'
}
Object.prototype.get = function(x) {
    return this[x];
}
var value = myObject.get('x');
```

In javascript prototype is the way of extending any property.